# Merging large number of .shp files via command line with ogrmerge.py

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, command-line, bash, ogrmerge

I have a directory containing many (about 100,000) .shp files.

I would like to merge them together via the command line using ogrmerge.py like this:

```
$ ogrmerge.py -single -o output.shp *inputs.shp
```

I get:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

I know I can generate a list of my input files using:

```
$ find -type f -name '*inputs.shp'
```

But I am struggling to find a way to pass that list to ogrmerge.py

Could anyone suggest a solution or alternative work-around?

Comment: you could try to loop other over the list of inputs shapefiles ?

Comment: Please notice that shapefile has a 2 GB size limit and you likely need to use some other format for output.

Comment: Try to make the paths as short as possible by placing the shapefiles in a folder with short pathname, and maybe rename the files.

Comment: 100k shapefiles means 400-800 *thousand* files in a single directory. This is 399-799 thousand too many. Not only would a coherent directory tree make access easier, it would make it faster, too

Answer (score 1):

Various commenters suggested this problem would be easier to deal with by creating subdirectories.

I wrote a python script to do this and also merge the shapefiles. It isn't elegant, but it works.

```
    import os
    import math

    bin_width = 1000 #number of files to move into each new directrory
    count = 100000 #Total number of files in the directory
    ext_list = ('.shp','.dbf','.shx','.prj') 
    from_dir = '/home/inputs/'
    to_dir = '/home/output/'

    def roundup(x,bin_width):
        return int(math.ceil(x / bin_width)) * bin_width

    def shp_merge(shape_name,input_shapefiles_path, output_shapefile_path,id_string):
        command3 = 'ogrmerge.py -single -o {}{}.shp {}*{}'.format(output_shapefile_path,shape_name,input_shapefiles_path,id_string)
        os.system(command3)

    out_shapefile_path = '{}new_directory/'.format(to_dir)
    os.system('mkdir {}'.format(out_shapefile_path))
    limit_list = range(0, roundup(count,bin_width), bin_width)
    for limit in limit_list:
       upper_lim = limit+bin_width
       mkdir_command  = 'mkdir {}{}_new_subdirectory'.format(to_dir,limit_list.index(limit))
        os.system(mkdir_command)
        file_list = range(limit, upper_lim, 1)
        for file in file_list:
            for ext in ext_list:
                file_name = '{}{}'.format(file,ext)
                command2 = 'cp {}{} {}{}_new_subdirectory/'.format(from_dir,file_name,to_dir,limit_list.index(limit)) 
                os.system(command2)

        shp_merge(limit_list.index(limit),'{}{}_new_subdirectory/'.format(to_dir,limit_list.index(limit)), out_shapefile_path, '.shp')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily set the particular length limit to "unlimited". There still is a limit but afaik it is in the Gigabytes of text. If your files are not too many and your filenames not too long, this should make the wildcard expansion possible.

```
$ ulimit -S -s unlimited
$ ogrmerge.py ...
```